# Adding USB device to rules.d

Tags: usb

I have trouble adding usb device to `rules.d list`, I want to be able to use it without root.

Here is my USB device:

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1162:2200 Secugen Corp.
```

And this is entry I made in `/etc/udev/rules.d/98-secugen-usb-device.rules`:

```
SYSFS{idVendor}=="1162", SYSFS{idProduct}=="2200", SYMLINK+="input/fdu05-%k", MODE="0660", GROUP="SecuGen" KERNEL=="uinput", MODE="0660", GROUP="SecuGen"
```

I'm not quite sure what is `SYMLINK+="input/fdu05-%k` part, it was set as this in `readme.txt`.

Unfortunately this rule does not work. Usually it is quite straight forward, add vendorId/productId and it works, but not this time.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:
This is output I get from `dmesg`:

```
usb 1-1.1.3: new high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
usb 1-1.1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1162, idProduct=2200
usb 1-1.1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 1-1.1.3: Product: SecuGen USB U20
usb 1-1.1.3: Manufacturer: SecuGen Corp.
```

This is how my `/dev/input` looks like:

```
├── by-id
│   ├── usb-LITEON_Technology_USB_Multimedia_Keyboard-event-kbd -> ../event0
│   ├── usb-Microsoft_Comfort_Mouse_6000-event-mouse -> ../event1
│   └── usb-Microsoft_Comfort_Mouse_6000-mouse -> ../mouse0
├── by-path
│   ├── pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1.2:1.0-event-kbd -> ../event0
│   ├── pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1.3:1.0-event-mouse -> ../event1
│   ├── pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1.3:1.0-mouse -> ../mouse0
│   └── platform-pcspkr-event-spkr -> ../event4
├── event0
├── event1
├── event10
├── event2
├── event3
├── event4
├── event5
├── event6
├── event7
├── event8
├── event9
├── mice
└── mouse0
```

Log I get from `unbuffer udevadm monitor --environment` :

```
UDEV  [4656.200575] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.3 (usb)
ACTION=add
BUSNUM=001
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/016
DEVNUM=016
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.3
DEVTYPE=usb_device
ID_BUS=usb
ID_MODEL=SecuGen_USB_U20
ID_MODEL_ENC=SecuGen\x20USB\x20U20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20
ID_MODEL_ID=2200
ID_REVISION=2206
ID_SERIAL=SecuGen_Corp._SecuGen_USB_U20
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ffffff:
ID_VENDOR=SecuGen_Corp.
ID_VENDOR_ENC=SecuGen\x20Corp.\x20\x20\x20\x20
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Secugen Corp.
ID_VENDOR_ID=1162
MAJOR=189
MINOR=15
PRODUCT=1162/2200/2206
SEQNUM=1702
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
UDEV_LOG=6
USEC_INITIALIZED=56185634

UDEV  [4657.235375] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.3/1-1.1.3:1.0 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.3/1-1.1.3:1.0
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Secugen Corp.
INTERFACE=255/255/255
MODALIAS=usb:v1162p2200d2206dc00dsc00dp00icFFiscFFipFFin00
PRODUCT=1162/2200/2206
SEQNUM=1703
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
UDEV_LOG=6
USEC_INITIALIZED=186134
adb_user=yes
```

Distro: `Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)`

Comment: Sorry, did not make my problem clear. It just doesn't work. Usually it is quite straight forward, add vendorId/productId  and it works, but not this time

Comment: What distro are you doing this on? It won't work with `systemd` based distros.

Comment: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

Comment: Sorry. Game over. `udev` isn't used on Jessie.

Comment: So how do I add rules for my USB devices ?

Comment: Sorry, don't know. Suggest you ask a new question with this new information (i.e. Jessie + `systemd`) and see if anyone else can help. Or revert Jessie to `init`+`udev` like I have

Comment: I did upgrade from older system, so I still have udev

Answer (score 1):

You've got this rule

> ```
> SYSFS{idVendor}=="1162", SYSFS{idProduct}=="2200", SYMLINK+="input/fdu05-%k", MODE="0660", GROUP="SecuGen" KERNEL=="uinput", MODE="0660", GROUP="SecuGen"
> ```

The `SYMLINK` entry adds a symlink for the device to `/dev/input/fdu05-%k`, where `%k` is replaced by the kernel name for this device. (You can see this in the [man page for udev(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/udev).)

You have two `GROUP` definitions; only one is expected.

Do you have the Linux group "SecuGen" defined? You can run `getent group SecuGen` to see if it's defined, or on a simple system just look in `/etc/group`. If not you'll need to add it so that the rule can set the device to that group.

Comment: So if everything worked correctly then I should see symlink in /dev/input/input , right ? I don't have one there http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=CRxec9Un

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to Unix & Linux StackExchange!

The only thing that you seem to be asking is the meaning of `SYMLINK+="input/fdu05-%k"` part in the `udev` rule.
This tells `udev` to automatically create a symbolic link to your device under `/dev/input/` with the name `fdu05-<kernel name of the device>`

But I understand that, since you mentioned that you don't want to be `root` to use the device, that's your main goal for this rule, right?
If you see, the important part is the user rights part of the rule, that is, `MODE` and `GROUP`. For security reasons, leave the mode as 0660 (r/w permission to owner and group, but no others) and check that your user is part of the group "SecuGen". This can be checked easily running in the terminal

```
id <username>
```

If the user is not part of the group, add it running

```
# usermod -a -G <username> SecuGen
```

Of course, you can also change the rule so that `GROUP` has your desired user's group.

Finally, remember to restart `udev` whenever you change any rule, or, if you have `udevadm`, you can ask `udev` to reload the rules running

```
# udevadm control --reload-rules
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank You for response. I'm checking for /dev/input to see if it has created symlink, but it doesn't have any corresponding entry http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=CRxec9Un . It should be in "input" directory, perhaps I should create it?

Comment: have you restarted `udev` and reattached the device to trigger the rule?
No, you should not alter the contents of `/dev` directory.

Comment: Yes, I reloaded rules and reattached the device, even did full system restart. But nothing new appeared under /dev/input

Comment: Check the kernel logs with `dmesg` to see what is going on when you attach the device. You could also try and change the symlink in the rule so that it creates the link directly under `/dev`. 
Also, I might ask... is the device an input device? If not, it would be quite senseless to have it under the "input" directory anyway...

Comment: Yes it is input device (fingerprint reader). This is output I get from dmesg : http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=84tbpdRJ

Comment: Ok, logs seem to be fine, from kernel side at least... something is happening with `udev`then...
BTW, did you corrected your rule? As pointed out by another answer, you have twice "MODE" and "GROUP", I did not see it when I first answered your question.
The corrected rule would be `SYSFS{idVendor}=="1162", SYSFS{idProduct}=="2200", SYMLINK+="input/fdu05-%k", MODE="0660", GROUP="SecuGen", KERNEL=="uinput"`

Comment: yes I corrected it, but it didn't resolve this issue.